# Different output for Jupyter than Atom

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I've created a waterfall graph using Jupyter and Atom (as I'm looking for a decent substitute for Jupyter, specially when it's related to dataframe visualisation)

Thing is that I used the same exact code in both editors but the output of the graph is different.
Does someone have an explanation?

Here is the code used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#read excel file
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/python/HP/waterfall.csv',sep=';')
df['Measure']=df['Measure'].str.lower()
display(df)

#store values in different variables
x=df['Deal ID']
y=df['deal value (USD)']
measure = df['Measure']
text=df['deal value (USD)']

#let's create the figure
fig = go.Figure(go.Waterfall(
    measure=measure,
    x=x,
    y=y,
    text=text,
    textposition="outside",
    decreasing = {"marker":{"color":"Maroon", "line":{"color":"red", "width":2}}},
    increasing = {"marker":{"color":"Teal"}},
    totals = {"marker":{"color":"deep sky blue", "line":{"color":"blue", "width":3}}},
    showlegend=False
    ))

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, visible=False)
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(title='Total deal value per customer X', height=470,
                   margin=dict(t=90, b=20, l=70, r=70),
                   hovermode="x unified",
                   xaxis_title='QvsQ ', yaxis_title="deal value in USD",
                   plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                   #paper_bgcolor='#333',
                   title_font=dict(size=25, color='#8a8d93', family="Lato, sans-serif"),
                   font=dict(color='#8a8d93'))
```

Atom otput:[image: Atom output]

Jupyter output: [![Jupyter output][2]][2]

Thanks
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYPEG.png

Comment: Not answering your question, but if you're looking for an alternative to Jupyter Lab/Notebook then take a look at Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @daniel.hillow Can you make sure that the different IDEs aren't set up with different versions of Python and / or Plotly?